# How to set a cookie inside a route handler using the state() method on the response object?

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

I'm trying to create a cookie under my route handler after my response object with the state method, but the cookie isn't appearing in any way. Even pasting many of the examples on the hapijs website is not working either.

My index.js:

```
const Hapi = require('hapi')

const server = new Hapi.Server
({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8000
})

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/',
  config: {
    handler: (request, h) => {
      return h.response(`Cookie!`).state('cookie-name', 'cookie-value');
    }
  }
})


async function start() {
  await server.start();
  console.log(`Server started at ${ server.info.uri }`);
}

start();
```

I was expecting 'cookie-name' to appear under 'name' in the developer console, as well as 'cookie-value' to appear as the 'value'. Nothing shows up and I am receiving this error message upon refreshing my localhost:

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error 
    Error: Invalid cookie value: [object Object]
    at exports.Definitions.internals.Definitions.internals.Definitions.format (/Users/cayden/Documents/egghead/introduction-to-node-servers-with-hapijs/lessons/12-hapi.js-managing-state-with-cookies/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/statehood/lib/index.js:361:24)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Establishing a cookie the way I am doing it is near an example I saw on their website. What am I missing that is causing my code to not produce the cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a cookie legitimately, you first need to configure the cookie by calling `server.state(name, [options])` method where name is the **cookie** name. And **options** are the objects to configure that cookie.

Add this lines of code to your existing code:

```
 server.state("cookie-name", {
        ttl: null,
        isSecure:  false,
        isHttpOnly: true,
        clearInvalid: false,
        strictHeader: true
  });

  server.route({
     method: 'GET',
     path: '/',
     config: {
         handler: (request, h) => {
            return h.response(`Cookie!`).state('cookie-name', 'cookie-value');
           }
       }
   })
```

Hopefully now you can see the cookie and it's value in the development browser.

Comment: Ah thank you, I ended up creating my server.state() before looking here, but was missing the 'isSecure: false' line for some reason because without it, I was receiving an error. I appreciate the help :)

Comment: welcome :). yes because `isSecure: true` indicates that the cookie should only work over https so the browser will not show the cookie if it's not a secured connection